# Create NSPredicate with ANY and two conditions for it

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I simply have two entities: `Product` and `Item`. Product may have many `items`: `Set<Item>`. `Item` has two properties: `isActive` and `identifier`.

Now I need to fetch all Products which have at least one `Item` with the following conditions met the same time:

- `identifier IN %@` //["1", "2"]
- `isActive = true`

  ```
    let format = "ANY (items.identifier IN %@ AND items.isActive = true)"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, ["1", "2"])
  ```

But I got exception: `Unable to parse the format ...`

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this -

```
let format = "SUBQUERY(items, $item, $item.identifier IN %@ AND $item.isActive = true).@count > 0"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: format, ["1", "2"])
```

Source : [NSPredicate Cheatsheet](http://realm.io.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/assets/downloads/NSPredicateCheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: Lets try it now;)